# HTML Force introduce break/new line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a table cell with some fixed width...

Now the content/text charcter length inside this cell varies and cannot always have a space in between which causes the layout to break slightly.

I tried fixing by adding the CSS word-wrap:break-word
But for some reason, this does not work always.

How do I make sure that my text breaks to the next line even if it does not have a space in between ?

Comment: I have already tried that...does not work..

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I'll not be able to show the exact code...as there are a lot of CSS, but just to give an idea, I have added a jsfiddle...URL : http://jsfiddle.net/Dnzra/

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, where did you fix the cell width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your jsfiddle so that it can work :

**EDIT**
http://jsfiddle.net/Dnzra/2/

All you have to do, is to add : `style="table-layout: fixed"` to the table style and some fixed width to your cells.

Comment: Thx a lot for the help...but in the updated fiddle, I still see the long text in the same line and does not actually wrap to the next line..

Comment: Thx again...So do I need to specify the td width in % ? I am getting a text overlap (as in your previous fiddle)

Comment: @testndtv : Well, you can remove the width. As I'm using Chrome, I noticed that It gives automatically the same width to your cells (You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/Dnzra/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The practical solution is to insert the tag `<wbr>` at any point where a direct line break is permissible, e.g.

```
<td>MaxUName<wbr>MaxUName<wbr>MaxUName<wbr>MaxUNa</td>
```

To get somewhat better browser coverage for the good old `<wbr>` (which never made its way to any standard but is alive and kicking), add the following into your style sheet:

```
wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

More info: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#wbr

Comment: Actually my text content is dynamic (coming from database)...So I cannot just edit it as it is...Is there some other way to fix this?

Comment: The CSS setting `word-wrap:break-word` has limited browser support. If you think that line breaks are permitted everywhere, you can insert `<wbr>` after each character when processing the dynamic data you get from the database, or maybe client-side in JavaScript.